# AgoraKit Agora.io `videoView` inside `UICollectionViewCell`, reload issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, agora.io

I am using agora kit v3.0.1 for video call purpose inside my app. Since I wanted to change the layout of video call view, I decided to use collection views.

The problem I am facing with collection views is that the videoView of agora gives black screen everytime I use reloadData() method of collectionView. The only way I managed to make it work is by calling `deleteItems` and `insertRows` methods of collectionView. But frequently this method crashes as the datasource does not match with after collection view update datasource. Is there any way I could use the reloadData() method without getting black screen?

Here is the code for `cellForRow`

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoCallCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCallCollectionViewCell
        cell.delegate = self.delegate
        cell.videoCallLayout = videoCallLayout
        
        if let quizChannel = quizChannel, let membersInfo = quizChannel.members_info {
            
            // set channel to cell
            cell.quizChannel = quizChannel
            
            let memberInfo = membersInfo[indexPath.item]
            
            // set memberInfo to cell
            cell.memberInfo = memberInfo
            
            if let remoteID = memberInfo.uid {
                
                // set agora video view to cell
                let videoCanvas = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
                videoCanvas.uid = UInt(remoteID)
                videoCanvas.view = cell.videoView
                videoCanvas.renderMode = .hidden
                
                if let user_channel_id = quizChannel.user_channel_id, remoteID == user_channel_id {
                    
                    // if local video view
                    agoraKit?.setupLocalVideo(videoCanvas)
                    
                } else {
                    
                    // if remote video view
                    agoraKit?.setupRemoteVideo(videoCanvas)
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

And whenever any `uid` joins or leaves the channel I call this function

```
func insertOrRemoveParticipantsWithNewQuizChannel(quizChannel: QuizChannel, uid: UInt?, action: String?) {
        
        if let uid = uid {
            // insert of remove new member
            
            print("Agora uid != nil : \(uid)")
            
            if let existingMemberInfo = self.quizChannel.members_info, existingMemberInfo.count != 0 {
                
                print("Agora existingMemberInfo count != 0 : \(uid)")
                
                if let action = action {
                    
                    self.quizChannel = quizChannel
                    
                    if action == "remove" {
                        
                        if let index = existingMemberInfo.firstIndex(where: { (memberInfo) -> Bool in
                            return memberInfo.uid ?? 0 == uid
                        }) {
                            // member's video view index found
                            
                            // remove member from the memberInfo
                            let newMemberInfo = quizChannel.members_info?.filter({ (memberInfo) -> Bool in
                                return memberInfo.uid ?? 0 != uid
                            })
                            
                            // set new memberInfo
                            self.quizChannel.members_info = newMemberInfo
                            
                            // remove member from the collectionview, FREQUENT CRASH
                            collectionView.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)])
                        }
                        
                    } else if action == "add" {
                        
                        if let memberInfos = quizChannel.members_info {
                            // for all members
                            for (index, memberInfo) in memberInfos.enumerated() {
                                // if cell corresponding to this member is nil
                                if collectionView.visibleCells.first(where: { (cell) -> Bool in
                                    if let cell = cell as? VideoCallCollectionViewCell {
                                        return cell.memberInfo?.uid == memberInfo.uid
                                    }
                                    return false
                                }) == nil {
                                    // insert a new cell, FREQUENT CRASH
                                    collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)])
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    // update rest of the cell's UI based in quiz channel
                    updateAllCellsUIForQuizChannel(quizChannel: quizChannel)
                    
                }
                
            } else {
                
                print("Agora existingMemberInfo count == 0 : \(uid))")
                
                // no members yet reload the collectionview
                self.quizChannel = quizChannel
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
            
        } else {
            
            print("Agora uid == nil)")
            
            // update view of cells for admin flow change, WORKS FINE
            updateAllCellsUIForQuizChannel(quizChannel: quizChannel)
            
        }
        
    }
```

The above method cashes frequently while deleting or inserting a new cell.

OR

Is there any other way to implement Agora kit with flexible layout? I already have tried the master example of Agora on github, but doesn't seem to fulfil my requirement and is too complex.
Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use a collection view to display video feeds without issues in this project:
https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/iOS-UIKit/blob/main/Sources/Agora-UIKit/AgoraCollectionViewer.swift

In this example only one canvas exists for each speaker, and using the `willDisplay cell` delegate method the canvas.view is set as a subview of the cell.

I think what's happening for you is you're creating a new canvas and setting it to the same user ID as a previous one rather than keeping a record. You cannot have two canvases rendering the feed from the same user, so that's probably why you're getting a blank screen.

Comment: Could you please look into this one as well, since you seem knowledgeable? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73065460/agora-io-videocanvas-gets-recycled-between-uicollectionviewcells?noredirect=1#comment129046799_73065460