# Agora.io VideoCanvas gets recycled between UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, agora.io

I’ve been using the agora SDK (audio only) for a while now, and I’m very pleased! Users can enter rooms of max 8 people and talk to each other. Now, I’m supposed to add a video feature, so they can enable their video stream at any time they want.

I’ve added the `AgoraRtcEngine_iOS 3.7.0` pod and this is how I initialize the agora engine:

```
agoraKit = AgoraRtcEngineKit.sharedEngine(withAppId: AppKeys.agoraAppId, delegate: self)
     
agoraKit?.setChannelProfile(.liveBroadcasting)
agoraKit?.setClientRole(.broadcaster)
agoraKit?.enableVideo()
agoraKit?.muteLocalVideoStream(true)
agoraKit?.muteLocalAudioStream(true)
agoraKit?.enableAudioVolumeIndication(1000, smooth: 3, report_vad: true)
```

This way, when a user joins a room, they have muted their audio and video streams, so they can enable it whenever they’re ready. The thing is, I’m using a `UICollectionView` to present the broadcasters. (everyone's user cell is visible at all times, so no reuse takes place, but collection view reloads happen **constantly**)

This is part of the cell setup (cellForItemAt), that handles the video view using a delegate:

```
private func setupVideoView(uid: UInt, isOfCurrentUser: Bool) {
    videoView.frame.size = avatarBackgroundView.frame.size
    videoView.layer.cornerRadius = avatarBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius
     
    if isOfCurrentUser {
      delegate?.localVideoSetupWasRequested(videoView: videoView)
    } else {
      delegate?.remoteVideoSetupWasRequested(uid: uid, videoView: videoView)
    }
}
```

And this is the conformance to the protocol:

```
extension RealTimeAudioAgoraService: NewVoiceRoomCellsDelegate {
  func localVideoSetupWasRequested(videoView: UIView) {
    guard !enabledVideoUIds.contains(currentUserRTCServiceId) else { return }
     
    let videoCanvas = setUpVideoView(uid: currentUserRTCServiceId, videoView: videoView)
    agoraKit?.setupLocalVideo(videoCanvas)
  }
   
  func remoteVideoSetupWasRequested(uid: UInt, videoView: UIView) {
    guard !enabledVideoUIds.contains(uid) else { return }
     
    let videoCanvas = setUpVideoView(uid: uid, videoView: videoView)
    agoraKit?.setupRemoteVideo(videoCanvas)
  }
   
  private func setUpVideoView(uid: UInt, videoView: UIView) -> AgoraRtcVideoCanvas {
    let videoCanvas = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
     
    videoCanvas.uid = uid
    videoCanvas.view = videoView
    videoCanvas.renderMode = .hidden
     
    // ------------------------------------
     
    enabledVideoUIds.append(uid)
     
    // ------------------------------------
     
    return videoCanvas
  }
}
```

As you can see, I keep track of all the uids I have enabled the video canvas for, so I do it only once for each user. The thing is something messes up the UI (see attached video) and even users with muted videos show the video canvas of others. It’s like the video canvas of each user is being cycled over every other user.

Any help will be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: reloading CollectionView definitely duque cell so this happen if you reloading cell on any action ?

Comment: Exactly! I stopped all the reloads and it stayed in place! (as it should) So what do I need to do now?

Comment: why are you reloading?

Comment: Multiple reasons, users leaving/joining the room, muting/unmuting audio and video streams, talking indication, etc...

Comment: You may use reload cell instead of reloading all collection view: collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath])